# Fun functional equation in a group: $af(ab)b=bf(ba)a$

Tags: group-theory, functions, finite-groups, functional-equations

Suppose we have a finite group $G$ and a function $f:G\to G$ that satisfies the following property for all $a,b\in G$:
$$af(ab)b=bf(ba)a$$
Under what conditions (or, for what groups $G$) can such a function $f$ exist? When such a function exists, what can we say about *how many* such functions there are? Are there any other interesting properties of $f$ implied by the above functional equation?

After playing around with this for a while, I noticed that

- If $G$ is abelian, then all functions $f:G\to G$ trivially satisfy this property
- For all $a\in G$, $a^2$ commutes with $f(e)$
- For all $a\in G$, $a$ commutes with $f(a)$
- For all $z\in Z(G)$ (the *center* of $G$) and all $a\in G$, $a$ commutes with $f(az)$

Comment: Are these necessary or sufficient conditions for $f$ to exist?

Comment: There are definitely examples where $G$ is non-abelian. For example, we can let $G$ be any finite non-abelian group satisfying $a^2 b^2 = b^2 a^2$ for all $a, b \in G$ (such as the group of upper-triangular $2\times 2$-matrices over $\mathbb F_3$), and set $f = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: For the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb F_3$ there exist several such functions (this is just Darij's example).

Comment: You mean "$f:G\to G$". The sign $\to$ denotes a map. The sign $\mapsto$ is distinct on purpose, and was coined to mean how it assigns elements.

Comment: If $f$ this property, then so does $f \circ \phi$ for any $\phi \in Aut(G)$. So we have a right action of $Aut(G)$ on these functions. You could ask what are the sizes of the orbits, how many orbits we have, etc. This might tell you something about the number of these functions.